# VB.NET Need to Halt/Terminate a Previously Called Close Form Method

Tags: vb.net

I have a report that contains a save button, whenever this button is clicked and saves (inserts/updates are successfully sent to our database), a boolean value tracks that the most recent changes have been saved. Users exiting this form are met with a dialog asking them if they want to save their changes if this boolean is false, meaning they haven't saved most recent changes.

The cancel button works great, except for when the user attempts to close the entire application (we have another built in "Are you sure you want to Exit application?" check). When the user does this and clicks Cancel I no longer want the "Are you sure you want to exit the application?" dialog to appear. This is getting called immediately after my YesNoCancel message box appears and the user clicks "Cancel".

I would like to just stop everything without cancelling the application, let the user pick up where they left of prior to clicking the "X" in the top right of the application. Thank you.

The code that handles the report closing dialog (MyBase.FormClosing event) (Below)

```
Dim result As Integer

If formClosing = False And recordsSaved = False Then
    result = MessageBox.Show("Save changes before exiting?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel)
Else
    Exit Sub
End If

If result = DialogResult.Cancel Then
    e.Cancel = True
    ' Need to stop the main "Leave application?" dialog from appearing when the user attempts to leave entire applciation on accident.
ElseIf result = DialogResult.Yes Then
    btnSave.PerformClick()
    formClosing = True              ' Keeps the dialog from looping
Else
    formClosing = True              ' Keeps the dialog from looping
End If
```

The code that handles the main application closing dialog (below).

```
Private Sub MainForm_Closing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Closing
    Dim vd As New VDialog()
    With vd
        .Owner = Me
        .WindowTitle = "Application Alert"
        .MainInstruction = "Exit Application"
        .Content = "Are you sure you want to close Application?"
        .MainIcon = VDialogIcon.Information
        .Buttons = New VDialogButton() { _
            New VDialogButton(VDialogResult.Yes), _
            New VDialogButton(VDialogResult.Cancel)}
        .Sound = VDialogSound.Question
        .Show()
    End With

    If (vd.Result = VDialogResult.Yes) Then
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
        SaveSettings()
        Application.Exit()
    Else
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Show your code you use in the Cancel button.  Is the above code from the FormClosing event?

Comment: I've added the code that handles the application closing dialog. The first chunk of code is the only code located in my "FormClosing" event of the report itself.

Comment: Doesn't vd have to use ShowDialog versus Show?  Are these two snippets on the same form?

Comment: No it does not. But what is happening is that "Cancel" is pressed on the cancel report dialog (the reports FormClosing event), and the code then jumps to the main applications Closing event since the "X" was clicked prior to any of this happening. These are not on the same form, the second bit of code is located on my main form that houses everything within.

Comment: ShowDialog blocks, Show doesn't.  So the form is shown, but the code below that line runs, which means vd.Result is never Yes, and the e.Cancel is always true.  I don't see how you say this works.  Why are you using Closing instead of FormClosing?  The closing event was deprecated a long time ago.

Comment: This MainForm code has to remain how it is, I am newer here and this has been in place for 10+ years. I inherited this, so I need something I can possibly add to my report's "FormClosing" that will halt everything and keep the code from jumping back to the MainForm code. Apologies for not explaining that sooner.

Comment: In the FormClosing handler, can you see if there is any information unique to either case in [FormClosingEventArgs.CloseReason](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs.closereason(v=vs.110).aspx). Possible values [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.closereason(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Is this an MDI application?

Comment: Yes, this is an MDI application. We have a main menu that is rather large, over 600 unique forms/reports that then open in the container, many can be open at once with tabs. And the unique eventarg is "UserClosing" for both events.

Comment: If you have to prevent the message from appearing in the main form's closing event, you will have to modify the code in the main form's closing event.  Right now, you have nothing in there that prevents it from showing that message.  Your child forms would probably have to set a flag in the main form via through a property or an event.

Comment: I didn't want to stop the message from appearing in the event, I just didn't want the event to trigger at all. Clicking the "X" triggers my report's closing event, I wanted that to be enough if the user clicks "Cancel" on my dialog. But, I will try the flag, that sounds like a great idea, thank you.